# PC Lint header error parsing, Error 129: declaration expected, identifier 'T_TEST_ID ' ignored

Tags: c, pc-lint

Running PC Lint analysis (v9.0), I am getting these errors on a source file *test_file.c* which is including a header file *test_file.h*

Here is how the `enum` is declared in *test_file.h*:

```
typedef enum {
  id_0,
  id_1,
  ...
  max_id
} T_TEST_ID;
```

This is the PC Lint output:

> -- Module: .../test_file.c
> Error 129: declaration expected, identifier 'T_TEST_ID' ignored
> Error 19: Useless Declaration
> Info 808: No explicit type given
> symbol 'T_TEST_ID', int assumed [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.1, required]

Using the verbose option I can confirm that *test_file.h* is being included as a header (hdr) to analyze *test_file.c*:

> Including file D:..\test_file.h (hdr)

After these errors I am getting many other errors due to `T_TEST_ID` is unknown to PC Lint. Any idea on what could be the problem and how to fix it? It seems to be a parsing error but maybe it could be a PC Lint configuration error.

*Note: This code is compiling fine, no errors/warnings reported from the compiler.*

Comment: It seems that you have found something that PC Lint does not understand.

Comment: Yes, maybe it could be. The strange thing is that there is another structure in the header file and it is parsing it correctly. I will keep investigating, thanks!

Comment: You might like to investigate the preprocessed output, perhaps there is another problem. Any decent compiler should be able to produce it, GCC for example with the `-E` option.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you happen to find the fix?

Comment: Hi! No, I didn't find the way to fix this issue, sorry.

Comment: Can you please share the full source code of 'test_file.h'? It is possible that some code before your `typedef` is causing the trouble.

Comment: Hi! The *test_file.h* is pretty simple, it only has a header inclusion at the top and a typedef declaration before the 'typedef enum' is that is causing problems.